# Deploying vue template in docker with nginx and pm2

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, web-deployment

My frontend has a separate router file called server.js which enables API calls to the php backend which I've hosted on AWS EC2.
Locally, I would use npm run serve and pm2 start server.js to serve the vue and router files and everything works perfectly but when I try to replicate the same thing on docker it doesn't work.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg; \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -; \
    apt-get install -y nodejs; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY server.js .
RUN mkdir /API
COPY /API /API
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"]
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I added the commands to install node.js and npm so that I can run the server.js file in the docker container

When I go to localhost:3000 I don't see anything hosted but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const path = require('path');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const router = express.Router()

const packages = require('./API/packages');
const searchPackages = require('./API/searchPackage');
const form_router = require('./API/forms');
const authRouter = require('./API/auth');
const static_page_router = require('./API/static_page');
const profile_router = require('./API/profile');
const file_fetch_router = require('./API/file_fetch');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
require('dotenv').config()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(cors());


// Enable if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS ELB, Nginx, etc)
// see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html
 app.set('trust proxy', 1);

 const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
     windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
     max: 100 // 100 requests from per IP
 });
 app.use(apiLimiter);

// const createAccountLimiter = rateLimit({
//     windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour window
//     max: 5, // start blocking after 5 requests
//     message:
//         "Too many accounts created from this IP, please try again after an hour"
// });
// app.post("/create-account", createAccountLimiter, function(req, res) {
// //...
// });




const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(staticFileMiddleware); //Both Imp

app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));


app.use(staticFileMiddleware); //Both Imp

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});


app.use(router)
app.use(async function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("requested URL =>" + req.url)
    next()
})

var secret = process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || 'SECRET'

app.use(cookieParser(secret));
//Cookies Configuration for saving token and userid

app.use(packages);
app.use(searchPackages);
app.use(static_page_router);
app.use(authRouter);
app.use(form_router);
app.use(profile_router);
app.use(file_fetch_router);


app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is running on port ' + port))
```

Comment: Could you also post the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: @jkoch 

`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                         NAMES
167dcdee0770   my-app    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 3000/tcp   cranky_moser`

Comment: Now the frontend isn't being served anymore either :/

Comment: Okay I had some time to take a look at your configs. The first thing I've noticed is that you are trying to run your express server and nginx in the same docker container. That is not a good idea. You should use one for nginx and one for express. You may want to take a look at docker-compose. With it you can write a yaml file to specify which containers  should be started and how they should be configured.

Comment: @jkoch so the reason why I did that is because first, I hosted the front end on docker and planned to run the express outside the container using pm2, but when I tried that, it wasn't proxying to the express server.

Comment: @jkoch I suspect this may be happening because something isn't included in the nginx.conf file but I don't know enough about it to point out exactly what.

Comment: From what I can see here currently your nginx container is just running nginx. The `CMD` you have set in your Dockerfile is just passed as parameter to the entryoint which is probably `/docker-entrypoint.sh`. I don't think this shell script from the nginx image will start your backend.

Comment: @jkoch I think there's some misunderstanding because I can't explain it well enough so I'll just show u the command I had previously run:

`docker run -d -p 80:80 my-app`

*docker container running in background*

`pm2 start server.js`

Comment: @jkoch this was before i added all the commands to add the express router into the docker container. At the time it was just the front end in the container and the server.js was running outside the container.